# calling a scala method passing each row of a dataframe as input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has two columns in it, has been created importing a .txt file.

sample file content::

```
Sankar Biswas, Played{"94"}
Puja "Kumari" Jha, Didnot
Man Women, null
null,Gay Gentleman
null,null
```

Created a dataframe importing the above file ::

```
val a = sc.textFile("file:////Users/sankar.biswas/Desktop/hello.txt")

case class Table(contentName: String, VersionDetails: String)

val b = a.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Table(p(0).trim,p(1).trim)).toDF
```

Now I have a function defined lets say like this ::

```
  def getFormattedName(contentName : String, VersionDetails:String): Option[String] = {
    Option(contentName+titleVersionDesc)
  }
```

Now what I need to do is I have to take each row of the dataframe and call the method getFormattedName passing the 2 arguments of the dataframe's each row.

I tried like this and many others but did not work out ::

```
val a = b.map((m,n) => getFormattedContentName(m,n))
```

Looking forward to any suggestion you have for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're planning to perform higher order functions like `map` & `filter`, I would suggest you to use a `Dataset` instead. Also, I would use the `DataFrameReader` [**API**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) for reading your csv as Constantine already suggested - BTW, you can derive an _schema_ from a **case class**, and you can cast a `DataFrame` to a `Dataset[T]` where `T` is a case class, given that you can pattern match against your case class like a tuple. Also you can use tuples if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a structured schema and it can be represented by a dataframe. 
Dataframe has support for reading the csv input.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val customSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("contentName", StringType, true),StructField("titleVersionDesc", StringType, true)))

val df = spark.read.schema(customSchema).csv("input.csv")
```

To call a custom method on dataset, you can create a UDF(User Defined Function).

```
def getFormattedName(contentName : String, titleVersionDesc:String): Option[String] = {
    Option(contentName+titleVersionDesc)
  }

val get_formatted_name = udf(getFormattedName _)

df.select(get_formatted_name($"contentName", $"titleVersionDesc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`val a = b.map(row => getFormattedContentName(row(0),row(1)))`

Remember that the rows of a dataframe are their own type, not a tuple or something, and you need to use the correct methodology for referring to their elements.

Comment: The `apply` method in `Row` returns `Any`, you would have to cast the values after to pass them to the method. I would use `row.getAs[String](0)` instead.